# How to view interface spec from Framework files on Mac OS

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

I'm the maker of [stdVBA](http://github.com/sancarn/stdVBA), a library which attempts to extend the capabilities of office. I've been looking to add mac compatibility to stdVBA for a long time but sadly there are some hurdles.

In windows COM, if an object implements an IDispatch (or ITypeInfo) interface you can call functions on that object by name. This functionality likely is also embedded in the Microsoft Office frameworks on Mac OS. For instance when opening up `MicrosoftOLEAutomation.framework` I do find a function named `CallFunc` which might well be akin to `rtcCallByName` on windows. Unfortunately I can't determine the C declare spec of the function in the framework file...

On windows, you can export functions out of DLLs (although not their declspecs). Is there anything similar on Mac OS with a "Framework function viewer"?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but you can "Jump to Definition" by Command clicking on a variable or function in Xcode.

Comment: You want to decompile a framework into a usable .H file?

Comment: @skaak basically, yes

Comment: @koen do you need the source code to do that? or will a compiled framework do?

Comment: @Sancarn note sure, not at my Mac now. Did you try it?

Comment: @koen I don't have xcode installed... And unfortunately the download is huge... So no not yet for me either.