# Pass Elements in Variant Array as Arguments to ParamArray

Tags: vba, parameter-passing, user-defined-functions, wrapper, paramarray

## Background

I am creating a VBA function (UDF) called `MyUDF()`, which wraps [`CallByName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/callbyname-function).

**I wish to mimic *precisely* the signature and parametric behavior of `CallByName()`.  Furthermore, `MyUDF()` must copy its `Args()` argument to a modular variable `ArgsCopy` — a `Variant` array — whose elements are then passed by `MyUDF()` as further arguments to `CallByName()`.**

Don't ask why — it's a long story.

## Reference

`CallByName()` displays in the VBA editor like so

[image: 2]

and it is described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/callbyname-function) like so:

> ### Syntax
>
> **CallByName** (*object*, *procname*, *calltype*, [args()]_)
>
> The **CallByName** function syntax has these [named arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#named-argument):
>
> | Part | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | *object* | Required: **Variant** (**Object**). The name of the object on which the function will be executed. |
> | *procname* | Required: **Variant** (**String**). A string expression containing the name of a property or method of the object. |
> | *calltype* | Required: **Constant**. A constant of type **vbCallType** representing the type of procedure being called. |
> | *args()* | Optional: **Variant** (**Array**). |

It appears that "`args()`" is actually a [`ParamArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-parameter-arrays), rather than a simple `Variant` array, but without further documentation, I can't be perfectly sure.

## Format

My tentative design is of the following form:

```vb
' Modular variable.
Private ArgsCopy() As Variant


' Wrapper function.
Public Function MyUDF( _
    ByRef Object As Object, _
    ByRef ProcName As String, _
    CallType As VbCallType, _
    ParamArray Args() As Variant _
)
    ' ...
    
    ' Copy the argument list to the modular variable.
    ArgsCopy = Args
    
    ' ...
    
    ' Pass the arguments (and modular variable) to 'CallByName()'.
    MyUDF = VBA.CallByName( _
        Object := Object, _
        ProcName := ProcName, _
        CallType := CallType, _
        Args := ArgsCopy _
    )
End Function
```

### Displayed Signature

In contrast to `CallByName()`, `MyUDF()` displays in the VBA editor like so, and concludes with `ParamArray Args() As Variant`:

[image: 5]

Only by changing `Args()` from a `ParamArray` to a `Variant` array (`ByRef Args() As Variant`) can we make them display identically:

[image: 6]

However, the latter would clash with the functional *behavior* described below for `CallByName()`.

### Parametric Behavior

Unfortunately, one cannot pass `ArgsCopy` to `Args` by name (`Args := ArgsCopy`), since `Args` is apparently a `ParamArray` and would thus accept only the unnamed arguments:

```vb
VBA.CallByName( _
    Object, ProcName, CallType, _
    ArgsCopy(0), ArgsCopy(1), ..., ArgsCopy(n) _
)
```

### Note

Please disregard the fact that `CallByName()` returns a `Variant`, which may (or may not) be an `Object` that must be [`Set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement).  I have already [accounted for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36898101) in my actual code.

## Question

How do I construct `MyUDF()`, and especially its `Args()` argument, such that

1. its signature mimics that of `CallByName()`, in both the `Type` and `Optional`ity of its parameters; **and**
2. it accurately passes to `CallByName()` any arbitrary set of arguments listed in `Args()`?

Ideally, `MyUDF()` will also

3. work properly on both **Mac** and Windows; **and**
4. display like `CallByName()` in the VBA editor:

[image: 6]

[image: 2]

This 3rd and 4th criteria are a bonus, but I don't *require* them.

## Suggestions

Visual Basic (VB) [suggests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/parameter-arrays#calling-a-paramarray) that one may pass arguments to its `ParamArray` as in `MyUDF()` above: the arguments are elements in an array of the same type as the `ParamArray`, and this array is supplied as a single argument.  However, I have found neither a documented nor an experimental equivalent in [VB***A***](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/info).

I did find these three VBA questions on Stack Overflow, but I lack the experience to apply their lessons here.

1. [**Passing an array of Arguments to CallByName VBA**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36313575)
2. [**Pass array to ParamArray**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20783170)
3. [**How to view interface spec from Framework files on Mac OS**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64333551)

### Change Method Signature

That first question has a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36316527), which changes the method signature for `CallByName()`, such that `Args()` is a single argument: an `Any` array.

However, I am unfamiliar with the **"`Any`" type**, and the [third question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64333551) (unanswered) makes me doubt this preprocessor "magic" could work on a **Mac**:

> ```vb
> #If VBA7 Or Win64 Then
>   Private Declare PtrSafe Function rtcCallByName Lib "VBE7.DLL" ( _
>     ByVal Object As Object, _
>     ByVal ProcName As LongPtr, _
>     ByVal CallType As VbCallType, _
>     ByRef args() As Any, _
>     Optional ByVal lcid As Long) As Variant
> #Else
>   Private Declare Function rtcCallByName Lib "VBE6.DLL" ( _
>     ByVal Object As Object, _
>     ByVal ProcName As Long, _
>     ByVal CallType As VbCallType, _
>     ByRef args() As Any, _
>     Optional ByVal lcid As Long) As Variant
> #End If
> ```

```vb
Public Function CallWithArgs( _
    ByRef Object As Object, _
    ByRef ProcName As String, _
    CallType As VbCallType, _
    ByRef Args() As Variant _
)
   CallWithArgs = rtcCallByName(Object, ProcName, CallType, Args)
End Function
```

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008, thanks for commenting!  I'm afraid I already tried the `ParamArray` approach.  Unfortunately, it won't pass the value of `ArgsCopy` to the `Args()` argument (a `ParamArray`) of `CallByName()`.  When I try to pass it — and `CallByName()` will only accept its `Args()` namelessly — then `CallByName()` simply treats `ArgsCopy` as a _single argument itself_ (with an array type) rather than as a list of multiple arguments.  The last element of `ArgsCopy` is then passed as the first argument to the procedure, which is named by `ProcName`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 In short, I'm trying to pass a `Variant` array _to_ the `ParamArray` in `CallByName()`.  I am _not_ trying to pass a `ParamArray` to a `Variant` array.

Comment: See [rtcCallByName](https://github.com/cristianbuse/Excel-VBA-ProgressBar/blob/f3323268d9e0a35ea674ab32259a3fcd01104792/src/ProgressBar.cls#L70) declaration from my repo. I pass the whole array in one go. I actually go a step further and make sure any ```ByRef``` flags are preserved (see ```RunObjMethod``` method). If I have time will write an answer here tomorrow.

Comment: @CristianBuse Thanks, I'll take a look!  Quick question: does it work on **Mac** too?

Comment: @Greg Unfortunately, no. For Mac I've build a [piramid](https://github.com/cristianbuse/Excel-VBA-ProgressBar/blob/f3323268d9e0a35ea674ab32259a3fcd01104792/src/ProgressBar.cls#L565) :)

Comment: @CristianBuse Ah, so I noticed.  Can we reliably say a `ParamArray` will always have a "reasonable" limit on size, namely `255` elements (for now)?  If so, then I can just write a script (in R) to autogenerate the pyramid, for all `MAX_PARAMARRAY_SIZE <- 255` of the VBA `Case`s.  We might even design a VBA module with pyramids for both `VBA.CallByName()` and `Application.Run()`, where the code is dynamically autogenerated.

Comment: The limit is not 255 parameters. It works with more than that, way more than 1000. The limit is the length of the code line i.e. how many arguments can you squeeze in a line of code even if that line of code is split into multiple text lines with the _ character. A piramid is simply not feasible - it gets ugly and big really quick. It would be nice if ```rtcCallByName``` would work on Mac.

Comment: @CristianBuse Ouch! _"It works with more than that, way more than 1000."_  I had misread this thread [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/excel-2007-vba-udf-argument-limits.640842/post-3180508), which discussed a limit of 254 arguments on calls to UDFs _within Excel formulae_.

Comment: I did not realize you were referring to UDF limit. Maybe that's indeed 254. I was referring to the limit for passing arguments to a param array. Still a 'piramid' is too much for 254.

Comment: @CristianBuse I just tested this in VBA, for an object `TestObject` with a method `CountArgs(requiredArg As Boolean, ParamArray Args() As Variant)`.  **I confirmed what you said**: that `CallByName()` can indeed pass an (essentially) **unlimited number of arguments** to `TestObject.CountArgs()`: `CallByName(TestObject, "CountArgs", VbMethod, 1, 2, 3, ..., 254, 255, 256, ...)`.

Comment: @CristianBuse For `Mac`, what about self-modifying code?  Some function `Caller(..., Args() As Variant)` can dispatch to `CallManyArgs(..., a() As Variant)`; but not before invoking the Sub `Modify(n As Long)`, which [dynamically alters](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) the contents of `CallManyArgs()`.  So `CallManyArgs()` would start out by hard coding `VBA.CallByName(obj, proc, type, a(0), a(1), a(2), ..., a(n), a(n + 1), ..., a(MAX))`.  Then `Modify()` would dynamically inject `)'`, to give us `VBA.CallByName(obj, proc, type, a(0), a(1), a(2), ..., a(n))', a(n + 1), ..., a(MAX))`.

Comment: @CristianBuse Obviously this solution is suboptimal in performance and is limited.  The character count for a call `Fun(0,0,0,...,0,0)`, which passes `n` arguments of `0` value to a Function `Fun(ParamArray Args() As Variant)`, is smaller than the character count to the hard-coded call `CallByName(a(0),a(1),a(2),..., a(n))`.  So the `CallByName(...)` call would run afoul of the line limit in VBA, before the original `Fun(...)` would ever do so.  And obviously an array passed to `CallManyArgs()` can hold as many as `2147483647` (?) elements, which are _far_ too many to hard code dynamically.

Comment: It would seem like there is no good solution for Mac. BTW, I've spent a couple of hours on Thursday to figure out if ```rtcCallByName``` is available on Mac but it's not unfortunately.

Comment: @CristianBuse I've just invited you to collaborate on my [**ArgMate**](https://github.com/GregYannes/ArgMate) repo.  The **`ArgMate`** module (`ArgMate.bas`) aspires to create a platform-agnostic API that standardizes the passing of arguments via an array: `CallByName()` is standardized as `Exe_Obj()` ("execute on object") and `Application.Run()` is standardized as `Exe_Mcr()` ("execute a macro").  Obviously Mac is limited to pyramids, which are autogenerated in R and inserted into a VBA stub (`Stub.bas`) to yield `ArgMate.bas`; this stub should be the origin of all VBA edits.

Comment: Thanks! Will have a look in the next few weeks.

Comment: Hi @CristianBuse!  Any thoughts on [**`ArgMate`**](https://github.com/GregYannes/ArgMate) so far?

Comment: Hi @Greg , unfortunately I was swamped in the last few weeks and I haven't properly looked into it yet but I haven't forgot about it. Something to note is that if an error is raised in the called procedure then ```Application.Run``` still raises the error even if you have a preceding ```On Error Resume Next```. I recently found out and was surprised as no doubt you will be if you didn't know already

Comment: Thanks @CristianBuse, good to know!  I think this consideration, about `Application.Run()`, would apply less to **`ArgMate`** itself, and more to my intended **`Sudo`** repo (which will likely depend on **`ArgMate`**).